# How to select Distinct ids for every IN Condition once

Tags: mysql

How would I select Id's Based on IN values. Basically I have a List of IN values But Id like to only select one ID from the table for each IN Value. I hope this doesn't sound to confusing but what I'm trying to accomplish is this.

| user_id | flavor | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Vanilla | yyyy-mm-dd |
| 1 | Vanilla | yyyy-mm-dd |
| 2 | Chocolate | yyyy-mm-dd |
| 3 | Chocolate | yyyy-mm-dd |
| 4 | Caramel | yyyy-mm-dd |
| 5 | Caramel | yyyy-mm-dd |
| 6 | Caramel | yyyy-mm-dd |
| 7 | Vanilla | yyyy-mm-dd |

From this List I'd like to Pull each flavor Once it can be any of the user_ids here I left date blank because  I think that might be a good field to look for it by to get the most recent users who signed up and filled out the survey for their favorite flavor.
would I use a group by and Distinct with an IN?
Something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `table` WHERE `flavor` IN ('Vanilla,Chocolate,Caramel') 
WHERE `date` 
yesterday GROUP BY flavor
```

Answer (score 0):

The code written down below creates

1. a table called "Data"
2. the content of the table.

After that the selection of the data records you are searching for takes place.

The query generates the following result:

| flavor | user_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Vanilla | 0 | 2021-06-07 20:00:00 |
| Chocolate | 2 | 2021-06-06 20:00:00 |
| Caramel | 4 | 2021-06-07 20:00:00 |

```
        CREATE TABLE Data (
        user_id INT,
        flavor VARCHAR(50),
        date TIMESTAMP);
    
    INSERT INTO Data (user_id ,flavor, date) VALUES (0,'Vanilla', '2021-06-07 20:00:00'), 
    (1,'Vanilla', '2021-06-06 20:00:00'), (2,'Chocolate', '2021-06-06 20:00:00'), 
    (3,'Chocolate', '2021-06-06 19:00:00'), (4,'Caramel', '2021-06-07 20:00:00'), 
    (5,'Caramel', '2021-06-06 20:00:00'),
    (6,'Vanilla', '2021-06-05 20:00:00'), (7,'Chocolate', '2021-06-05 20:00:00'), 
    (7,'Vanilla', '2021-06-05 20:00:00') ;
    
    SELECT 
    d.flavor, d.user_id, d.date
FROM
    Data d
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        flavor, MAX(date) AS latestDate
    FROM
        data
    GROUP BY flavor) lD ON ld.flavor = d.flavor
WHERE
    d.date = ld.latestDate
        AND d.flavor IN ('Vanilla' , 'Chocolate', 'Caramel');
```